# Цикл неправильно работает

Tags: c, циклы

Цикл правильно выполняется для нулевого значения, но не переходит на первое, а опять выполняется для нулевого и т.д. В коде я вроде бы пaраметр i нигде не обнуляю, подскажите что не так?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define DELIM " \t\n"
main()
{
    int i, n = 0;
    char base[100];
    FILE* fo, *fi;
    fo = fopen("D:\\TextFile.txt", "r");
    fi = fopen("D:\\TextFile1.txt", "w");

    for (i = 0; i < 8099; i++)
    {
        fgets(base, 100, fo);
        {
            fputs(base, fi);
            fclose(fo);
            fclose(fi);
            {
                char buf[BUFSIZ], * p;
                char base[100], ch;
                FILE* fw, *fq;
                fq = fopen("D:\\TextFile1.txt", "r");
                fw = fopen("D:\\TextFile2.txt", "w");

                while (fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, fq) && fputs(buf, fw) && buf[BUFSIZ] != 'q')
                    fclose(fw);

                fclose(fq);
            }
        }
        {
            char str[100], *p = str;
            FILE* fe, * fr;
            assert((fe = fopen("D:\\TextFile2.txt", "r")) != NULL);
            assert((fr = fopen("D:\\TextFile3.txt", "w")) != NULL);

            for (int l = 0; l < 1; l++)
            {
                fgets(str, 100, fe);
            }

            for (int n = 0; n <= 100; n++)
            {
                if (p[n] == ' ')
                    p[n] = '\n';
            }

            printf("%s\n", str);
            fputs(str, fr);
            fclose(fe);
            fclose(fr);
        }
        {
            char str1[1024];
            gets(str1);
            char str2[1024];
            FILE* fr, *fo;
            fr = fopen("D:\\TextFile3.txt", "r");
            fo = fopen("D:\\TextFile4.txt", "w");

            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            {
                fscanf(fr, "%s", &str2);
                fputs(str2, fo);

                if (strcmp(str1, str2) == 0)
                {
                    puts("da");
                    int s = i + 1;
                    n = j + 1;
                    printf("stroka =%i\nslovo =%i", s, n);
                    break;
                }
                else
                    puts("ne");
            }
        }

        if (n != 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Кажется понял ошибку: после первого fgets я закрываю TextFile, и во втором прохождении цикла программа заново его открывает и снова считывает первую строку, как исправить? i меняется при каждом повторении цикла - сначала 0, потом 1 и т.д., но считывает все равно первую строку.

Comment: Возможно, вы получаете переполнение буфера, которое перезаписывает переменную `i`... Попробуйте или добавить отладочный вывод, или прямо в отладчике последить за значением `i` - не меняется ли оно где-то по ходу работы.

Answer (score 0):

Просто не закрывайте файлы сразу в цикле - закрывайте их после выполнения цикла.

Answer (score -1):

Кажется понял ошибку: после первого fgets я закрываю TextFile, и во втором прохождении цикла программа заново его открывает и снова считывает первую строку, как исправить?
i меняется при каждом повторении цикла - сначала 0, потом 1 и т.д., но считывает все равно первую строку.

Comment: Это не похоже на ответ на вопрос, а скорее дополнение к нему. Лучше перенесите эту информацию в сам вопрос, а ответ удалите.